# How to classify text and predict if it belongs to the group or not?

Tags: nlp, supervised-learning

I am basically Python Postgres programmer and new to datas science and its tools.

I have around 78 million records which contains information like this:

| CostCenter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 110000032 | Hiring of vehicles |
| 110000032 | Hired vehicles |
| 110000032 | Vehicles hired |
| 110000032 | Hiriing of vehicles |
| 110000032 | Pay bill |
| 110000033 | Hiring of vehicle |

`CostCenter` is pre-defined (Master data) and `Description` is user entered field and there is no uniformity in what is entered into description.

**What is required:**
I want to have a binary split of those, where Hiring of Vehicles (all like matches) - 110000032 are true and remaining all false.

The false entries from the above would be 110000032 - Paybill (32 CostCenter is for Hiring of Vehicles) and 110000033 - Hiring of vehicle (33 is not for hiring of vehicle).

**What I have tried so far:**
Using RegEx is not useful because, I dont know the different patterns of free text (Description) entered by users.

I have used FTS (Full Text Search) of Postgre and tokenized the Description field and get all like matches for HIRE and VEHICLE.

What I am looking to do is, train a model so that based on the description, the system can display records whose CostCenter is not matching.

What is the correct approach? Supervised Learning? [Collobarative Filtering?](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/collaborative/basics) NLTK NLP?

Edited: I have around 3000 unique costcenters in 99 different combinations of the last 2 digits.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Sorry I don't understand the last sentence: do you mean that in the real problem you would have to deal with 3000 (or 99?) different classes like this? Or that you want to deal only this 'hiring vehicle' category, but it's among many others?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have to deal with numerous categories (8 digit code) like this. I have around 3000 unique categories (first 6 digits) and the last 2 digits can vary in 99 different ways for each category. I am working on n-gram/MLP model and will post results once evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. The 99 x 3000 = 297,000 possible classes (if I understood you correctly) makes this tricky with normal deep learning approaches: the softmax layer at the end gets very large.

If you want to go down that road, Amazon recommender systems have this issue, when trying to suggest which of their millions of project; see https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-torchrec/ as a good starting point.

You could also treat it as a *fraud detection machine learning* problem (google for those keywords will provide plenty of leads).

I'd do a variation on that idea, where a few typos are considered to be fine, but anything more is "fraud". I am going to assume you have an ideal string for each category. So "Hiring of Vehicles" is the desired string for 110000032. (If not, an SQL query can give you the most common value, can't it.)

For each category, calculate the edit distance from the ideal value. And write that back in as a new column in your database.

(It [looks like](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html) this can be done from inside Postgres; notice that `levenshtein_less_equal` is a more efficient version that is ideal for you, as you don't need to know the actual distance when it is high, you only care about if it needs a lot of edits or not.)

You can now define false entries as any over a certain edit distance, all from within the comfort of SQL. Those below an edit distance of say 3 could be UPDATEd, if you like your data clean.

Do you also need to automate fixing the remaining ones? The obvious way is to take each bad entry, and get edit distance against the ideal string for each category. That is potentially very slow, but there is a low-hanging fruit speed-up: try just the adjacent digits, and work out from there. So for each bad entry for 110000032, first try against 110000033 and 110000031. As soon as you a low edit distance, assume that was the typo and move it there. I'm betting you only need to try the other 9 last digits, to fix 90% of your bad entries.

Answer (score 0):

(Started as a comment but it might be worth an answer)

This is supervised learning, but the huge number of classes is likely going to be an issue. It might even cause trouble for the time needed to train a model and potentially the storage space. I'm not expert in this kind of case, I don't know if there are specific methods for it. I would suggest to at least simplify the problem a bit by focusing on the most frequent classes, since probably some of them are rarely used.  Even so, i suspect that it will be hard.

In principle apart from the number of classes it's a regular text classification problem: you could start with a basic model like Naive Bayes. The preprocessing is going to be important, probably you'd have to limit the number of features by removing rare words (use a minimum frequency), possibly using lemmas, removing stop words, this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Erwan, and as told by you, high number of classes is an issue. I am trying to narrow them down for model training. Could you pls suggest the framework to begin with? TensorFlow, Keras, PyTorch, Scikit-learn NLTK?? Thanks

Comment: @Oneflydown well I would start by seeing what a simple approach gives with sklearn, I'm thinking [with NB similar to this](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-using-naive-bayes-theory-a-working-example-2ef4b7eb7d5a). nltk could be used to lemmatize and/or remove stop words at preprocessing to improve perf. I'm not very knowledgeable about anything usable for this in DL, I suspect that the size of the problem limits your options. Mind that 300000 classes means that a random baseline classifier would get only 1/300000=0.0003% accuracy... it should be better of course, ...

Comment: ... but it might be hard to even reach an accuracy of 1%. This is why I suggest starting with the most frequent classes only, this could make the problem a bit more reasonable.